# What gets counted as "Healing Done"?

Tags: league-of-legends

What gets counted as "Healing Done" in the *League of Legends* stats?  The scoreboard after a game shows me doing all of 71 healing (some strangely small value), and other non-overt healers doing conspicuous amounts.

[image: Post-game scoreboard]

The enemy Graves had the summoner spell Heal, which perhaps accounts for his healing, but how did Malzahar or Zilean do that much healing?  Does spell vamp count as healing but not life steal (I had Bloodthirster for over half the game and easily healed thousands with it)?  Does shielding count (or what part of the shield gets beat on)?

Comment: Did you have lifesteal?

Comment: I know Zilean's ult counts as healing, but I don't know if it's credited towards him or the champ he revives.

Comment: Maybe it is if you have like will of the ancients or the other one with the attackspeed and lifesteal (forgot). That if they hit with it , it gives you healing.

Comment: Baron's buff also does healing that counts for the stats. This may be it.

Comment: Vlad with that much heal. It can only be spell vamp right? This is a completely uneducated guess, but it seems like the only explanation. Shen can heal off of using his Q. I am clueless about Garen. No way can healing done be regen, graves would have had more than 71hp regen over the entire match...

Comment: every healing done should be counted there however i guess this 1 is just bugged idk why.

Comment: @theorise In regards to Garen, I'm like 99% sure that his passive regen is counted as a spell effect as opposed to item based regen (e.g. Emblem of Valor, Philo. Stone), which would likely be counted in with the rest of healing spell effects, including other passives like Trundle's or Maokai's.

Comment: I doubt you still have it, but a pic of everyone's items would help immensely.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that your 71 HP "Healing" was a result of killing 2-3 neutral creep camp leaders while hurt over the course of the game and receiving the minor heal they now give on death as part of the jungle revamp. The tally shows you as killing 34 Neutral creeps. If you killed about 1/3 of them when you were hurt (so that the heal would have an effect) that comes out to around 71 HP.

Answer (score 1):

The Ziggs Patch Notes (serendipitously) presented a major clue to this:

> - Heal over time effects now show as health regen per 5 rather than discreet heals

Shen's <kbd>Q</kbd>, Ki Strike, is a Heal over Time. And look who has the top healing on the enemy team!

The other champions have so much healing because they hit Ki-Strike targets or were revived by Zilean's ult (as these are buffs, rather than direct effects, they count as healing for *their target*, and not the buff's provider).

As to your 71 - that's probably from a jungle creep's health relic. Either you didn't kill many jungle creeps, or you killed them while at full health from your bloodthirster (and thus didn't need the heal).

Here's a game with Shen post-patch.

[image]

The only one with significant healing now is Mordekaiser, who gets healing from his ult (it's a discrete heal on the initial nuke, and then each subsequent tick).

Comment: Love the post-game banter.

Comment: @Toast "I may have died 4 times compared to your 1, but I think we both know who the real winner is"

Answer (score 0):

I think i know, but don't shoot me if i'm wrong. But it might be because Zilean seems like a support char, and know support chars they mostly go with Philosopher's Stone. I think the health regen counts as healing done. It is the only solution i can think off.

update:I'm at work atm, but ill try and do some testing and find some references tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any concrete answers, but while browsing the forums, it seems that spellvamp, life steal, and HP regen don't count towards healing done.

It seems only <s>abilities</s> active healing counts as Healing Done.  Your 71 could be a result of a potion.

Forum links:
[someone explain to me the healing done graph?](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1685923)
[Post game stats: healing done](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1682866)
[Spellvamp =/= Healing Done?](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1717869)
[Akal Heal](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=445092)
[Olaf Healing Done: 190](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=949362)
[Healing done???](http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=159709)

Comment: doesn't your last sentence contradict itself?  If only abilities count towards healing, why would a potion (an item) show up on the chart?

Comment: @yx. - my guess is that (same like spells), it's actually active healing if you think about it (you need to click on a potion to heal yourself with it) whereas regular item regen is passive. I asked myself why 71HP, how could a potion heal for 71HP and not the full amount. But if you die during the time that potion is doing its magic, the process of healing stops (at 71HP in this case).

Comment: Yes, abilities should be replaced with active healing.

Comment: @pootzko, the only time I potted it ran the full course.  I think the healing I "did" was from creep kills.

Comment: maybe it was just "a game feature"... xD

Comment: No ignite, etc to limit it's effectiveness? You remember that you specifically only used one pot?  Where you close to full health when you used it?

Comment: Potions provide hp/5, not direct healing.